# Turn Pi Screen on and off programmatically

Tags: screen-saver

I have a RPi3B with the RPi 7inch screen attached. I am running Jessie, but will re-image it to stretch soon. I would like to turn the screen on or off via Python. For example, when I ask what is the time I want the screen to wake up as I display a certain webpage on the screen that has time and date. Then after a certain amount of time I want it to go blank again.

How can I control the screen display Python or via command line?

I have found posts that explain how to stop the screen timeout, but none that explain how to toggle back and forth.

Answer (score 3):

**Command line:**

OFF:

```
sudo -E sh -c 'echo 1 > /sys/class/backlight/rpi_backlight/bl_power'
```

ON:

```
sudo -E sh -c 'echo 0 > /sys/class/backlight/rpi_backlight/bl_power'
```

TIP: I define the above as `backlight_off` and `backlight_on` in `~/.bash_aliases`. Be sure to save that file elsewhere, since you'll lose it if  you re-image.

**Python:**

- First save the above as `backlight_off.sh` and `backlight_on.sh` (with proper `#!/bin/sh` shebang header), maybe saved to `/usr/local/bin/` if you want it available in your $PATH
- ... then you can use Python `subprocess()` to invoke these new scripts. Use the "command syntax" to run the script files, and the script's own shell should take care of things.
- If you are doing this in a web application (and therefore rightly concerned about security), then avoid use of variables around these calls (hardcode the Python subprocess calls), and get the code peer-reviewed.

If you read Subprocess documentation, it may contain suggestions to *not* use it to run shell scripts. That's fine in most cases, but not in this one.

**FYI - "-c" is a life-saver**

The "-c" option is often used to "wrap" commands into a user context, like sudo. You'll see this in some `cron` files, or used heavily by the `Docker` community.

**More reading (and doing this in "pure" Python):**

- https://github.com/molejar/pyFDT

There are downsides to this, and you may need to run your Python script as sudo (not a good idea, generally) or make configuration changes to your Pi. You'll learn a bit going down this rabbit hole..

**FYI this also worked:**

```
pi@pi3:~ $ echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/rpi_backlight/bl_power
1
```

That works because the redirect is executed as sudo, but there is the unintended side-effect of `1` output text.

Answer (score 1):

Although not Python these is commands I use to turn the screen off and on.

turn screen OFF

```
echo 1 > /sys/class/backlight/rpi_backlight/bl_power
```

turn screen ON

```
echo 0 > /sys/class/backlight/rpi_backlight/bl_power
```

Note: I did have to run these via sudo/root

Comment: Thanks. I have tried that, but I get "-bash: /sys/class/backlight/rpi_backlight/bl_power: Permission denied" even when using sudo. I dont quite understand why sudo doesnt override the security

Comment: how bizarre, what permissions does it report `ls -l /sys/class/backlight/rpi_backlight/` ?

Comment: -r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun 10 21:11 actual_brightness
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun 10 21:11 bl_power
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun 10 21:11 brightness
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Jun 10 21:11 device -> ../../../rpi_backlight
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun 10 21:11 max_brightness
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 Jun 10 21:11 power
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Jun 10 21:11 subsystem -> ../../../../../class/backlight
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun 10 21:11 type
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun 10 21:11 uevent

Comment: I ran "sudo chmod 777 /sys/class/backlight/rpi_backlight/bl_power" and that then allowed me to run the commands you mentioned. However they didnt seem to affect the screen.

Comment: I dont think this works with Stretch. As it doesnt seem to help with my Pi. I would be interested to know if someone else has tested this.

Comment: @LeeMelbourne Ensure you've disabled console blanking: https://github.com/notro/fbtft/wiki/Boot-console#console-blanking

Comment: @LeeMelbourne Most likely you're using `sudo` incorrectly. `sudo` works on commands, not on redirections, so `sudo command > file` runs the command elevated, but accesses the files with your initial permissions.

Comment: Is this supposed to turn off the screen or to turn it dark? I have a 3rd party screen and had to replace ```rpi_backlight``` with ```10-0045``` (the rest looks the same). However, the display only gets a bit darker, not turned off, when running the commands...

Answer (score 1):

ok, so the permissions error reported in the comments is not pi specific, it's unix/linux specific.

`sudo echo 1 > /sys/class/backlight/rpi_backlight/bl_power`

will give you `-bash: /sys/class/backlight/rpi_backlight/bl_power: Permission denied` because the `sudo` is only applying to the echo statement, not the redirection of output to the /sys/ file.

One option is to `sudo bash` followed by `echo 1 > /sys/class/backlight/rpi_backlight/bl_power`.

Alternatively, `sudo sh -c "echo 1 > /sys/class/backlight/rpi_backlight/bl_power"`.  That takes everything in double quotes and runs it in a shell that has had it's privileges elevated.